# Receive string data via Bluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I'm creating a simple BLE app that communicates with a single peripheral. The phone acts as the central. I have an iPad which I'm using as the peripheral for testing. It has the app [LightBlue](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-explorer/id557428110?mt=8) installed to simulate a peripheral. The peripheral is supposed to send a string of data in this format.

> TEM:25.11 | HUM:70 | PM10:43 | PM25:32

So I created a blank virtual peripheral in LightBlue with one service.

[image]

[image]

Below is my code for Bluetooth connectivity handling.

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    fileprivate let serviceUUID = CBUUID(string: "19B10010-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214")
    fileprivate let characteristicUUID = CBUUID(string: "19B10011-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214")

    fileprivate var manager: CBCentralManager!
    fileprivate var peripheral: CBPeripheral!
    fileprivate var characteristic: CBCharacteristic!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        stopScan()
    }

    fileprivate func startScan() {
        manager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [serviceUUID], options: nil)
    }

    fileprivate func stopScan() {
        manager.stopScan()
    }

    fileprivate func disconnectFromDevice() {
        guard let peripheral = peripheral else { return }
        manager.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral)
    }

    fileprivate func restoreCentralManager() {
        manager.delegate = self
    }

}

// MARK: - CBCentralManagerDelegate
extension ViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch central.state {
        case .unsupported:
            print("Unsupported")
        case .unauthorized:
            print("Unauthorized")
        case .poweredOn:
            print("Powered On")
            startScan()
        case .resetting:
            print("Resetting")
        case .poweredOff:
            print("Powered Off")
        case .unknown:
            print("Unknown")
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print("Discovered \(String(describing: peripheral.name)) at \(RSSI)")

        if peripheral.name == nil || peripheral.name == "" {
            return
        }

        if self.peripheral == nil || self.peripheral.state == .disconnected {
            stopScan()

            self.peripheral = peripheral
            central.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        peripheral.delegate = self
        peripheral.discoverServices([serviceUUID])
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {

        self.peripheral = nil
        central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        self.peripheral = nil
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : Any]) {
    }
}

// MARK: - CBPeripheralDelegate
extension ViewController: CBPeripheralDelegate {
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        guard let services = peripheral.services else { return }
        print("No. of services: \(services.count)")

        for service in services {
            print(service.uuid)
            if service.uuid == serviceUUID {
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
            }
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else { return }

        for characteristic in characteristics {
            print("characteristic: \(characteristic.uuid)")
            if characteristic.uuid == characteristicUUID {
                self.characteristic = characteristic
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
                peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
            }
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        print(error)
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {        
        if characteristic.uuid == characteristicUUID {
            print("Got reply from: \(characteristic.uuid)")
            print(characteristic.value)
            if let data = characteristic.value, let string = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                print(string)
            } else {
                print("No response!")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The discovering and connecting part works just fine. The problem is I don't receive that data string from the peripheral.

The method `peripheral(_:didUpdateValueFor:error:)` does get fired. I get the *Got reply from: 19B10011-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214* output in the console. However when I tried to see if there's any data by printing out the `characteristic.value`, it returns `nil`.

Not sure if it's something wrong with my code. Or I've configured the peripheral on LightBlue wrong. Does LightBlue send out data automatically? I don't see any *Send* button or anything anywhere either.

I uploaded a demo project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hkkoa85a6r3j039/BLEDemo.zip?dl=0) as well.

Comment: What's your New Virtual Peripheral configuration ?

Comment: @VarunNaharia In the LightBlue app?

Comment: yes I'll configure the same and then I'll try to find problem

Comment: The above two screenshots show all the configurations I did.

Comment: there is option blank, Alert Notification etc which one to choose ?

Comment: Ah that. I created a Blank one. Then changed the UUIDs of the service and the characteristic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LightBlue configuration showing that you can only write value on that particular characteristic You have to make this read also